# Interconnection errors between Jenkins and Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, build, http-status-code-403, artifactory

I recently got an interconnection errors between Jenkins and Artifactory upon deployment of the job, the error re-appears frequently.

I would like to know from where the problem comes, and what’s the cause of the outbreak of the error.

We use the plugin version of Artifactory: Artifactory Plugin : 2.1.8

Stack trace in Jenkins log :

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory. Failed to send build info: HTTP response code: 403. HTTP response message: Interdit -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory.
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
     at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
     at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
     at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
     at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
     at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory.
     at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:87)
     at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:132)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:170)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
     ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send build info: HTTP response code: 403. HTTP response message: Interdit
     at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.throwHttpIOException(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:642)
     at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.sendBuildInfo(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:240)
     at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:85)
     ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're using a *very old* version of the plugin, released in August 2013 — the current newest version was released in April 2015.  So you should ideally upgrade and check if you have the same issue.

But as the HTTP status code and message say, you're being forbidden from accessing the server.  So most likely you have the wrong credentials, or your account has been blocked, or similar.

Make sure that the correct URL and credentials for the relevant server are entered in the Jenkins system config under Manage Jenkins → Configure System → Artifactory.

For each server configured, there is (since version 2.2.0) a <kbd>Test Connection</kbd> button which you can click to verify whether your server credentials are correct.

Comment: thank you Christopher for you response, 
I checked the job configurations and everything is configured correctly, and I think it’s not a problem of permissions or access, because the build is passed successfully many times then he failed with error 403 without any changes in the job configurations, this problem is random and only happens on this project, it’s the only project that is experiencing this problem.

Comment: @Yalami did you end up finding out what the issue was.?